# Oracle Group by based on next row value

Tags: sql, oracle

We are trying to get a group by result by checking the next rows value.

**Sample Data**:

```
Table A

COL1 COL2 COL3
---- ---- ----
B    BUY     1
B    SELL  1.2
B    SELL    2
C    BUY     3
C    SELL    4
C    BUY     5
```

**Result**:

```
COL1 COL2 COUNT(1)
---- ---- --------
B    BUY         1
B    SELL        2
C    BUY         1
C    SELL        1
C    BUY         1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have ordered by `COL3`; if this is the case then:

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       change - COALESCE( LAG( change ) OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY change ), 0 )
         AS cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         CASE LEAD( col2 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 )
           WHEN col2
           THEN NULL
           ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col3 )
         END AS change
  FROM   a
)
WHERE  change IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a difference of row numbers approach:

```
select col1, col2, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3) as seqnum_2,
      from t
     ) t
group by col1, col2, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

This identifies groups of adjacent `col2` values based on the ordering in `col3`.

Comment: I am losing the ordering of the rows with the above query , is there a way the order of the result is preserved ?

Comment: @HarshMehta and how do you determine the row order in your dataset?  order is not guaranteed w/o an order by so what would you order by in your example data?

Comment: @HarshMehta . . . I don't know what you mean.  This seems like the simplest way to get what you want.